# How to add a document to the Alfresco Repository with Java code?

Tags: java, alfresco

**EDIT: Apparently I had to make an AMP and map it to Alfresco.war. But now I can't access the code I wrote, so I guess I'll have to use Webscripts and the like. Can someone provide an example of how to add a document to the Alfresco Repository with a Java backed webscript?**

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I've searched google-wide for a way to add a document to the Alfresco Repository with Java code. But I was not able to find a way that would work. I know how I can add a document to the Repository: use the NodeService. But the problem is that I cannot get an instance of the NodeService. I've tried to inject it with @Autowired, I've tried using a bean and I've tried using an ApplicationContext. None of the ways worked...

Way #1:
Injection in a class:

```
@Autowired
NodeService nodeService
```

---

Way #2:
In service-context.xml:

```
<bean id="somerandombeanname" class="management.FileManager" >
    <property name="moduleId" value="${project.artifactId}" />
    <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry" />
    <property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService" />
    <property name="transactionService" ref="TransactionService" />
    <property name="contentService" ref="ContentService" />
</bean>
```

In the class I added a getter and setter for all the services and the serviceRegistry:

```
private NodeService nodeService;

public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
}
```

---

Way #3:

```
appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:alfresco/application-context.xml");

serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) appContext.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);

nodeService = serviceRegistry.getNodeService();
```

Ways #1 and #2 gave me a NullPointerException simply stating the NodeService is null. Way #3 gave a mile long StackTrace because of an AlfrescoRuntimeException because it failed to initialize a keystore:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ssl.keyStore' defined in class path resource [alfresco/encryption-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04180000 Failed to initialize keystore:
Location: E:/Alfresco/alf_data/keystore/ssl.keystore
Provider: null
Type:     JCEKS
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at management.FileManager.<init>(FileManager.java:36)
    at simple.start.main(start.java:25)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 04180000 Failed to initialize keystore:
Location: E:/Alfresco/alf_data/keystore/ssl.keystore
Provider: null
Type:     JCEKS
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.loadKeyStore(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:566)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.safeInit(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:537)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.init(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1580)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.findResource(URLClassPath.java:494)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:176)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:551)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:549)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:548)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.resolveURL(ClassPathResource.java:147)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.exists(ClassPathResource.java:135)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.SpringKeyResourceLoader.getSafeInputStream(SpringKeyResourceLoader.java:67)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.SpringKeyResourceLoader.loadKeyMetaData(SpringKeyResourceLoader.java:133)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl$KeyInfoManager.loadKeyMetaData(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:1016)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl$KeyInfoManager.<init>(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:998)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.getKeyInfoManager(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:395)
    at org.alfresco.encryption.AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.loadKeyStore(AlfrescoKeyStoreImpl.java:560)
    ... 27 more
```

Yes, the keystore exists and yes I have regenerated a new keystore.

I'm using Alfresco 5.0.1 and I'm working on the **Repository** side (not Share).

Comment: Why don't you use a Java backed webscript to perform what you need?

Comment: Because I'm working on the Repository side, not Share.

Comment: WebScripts can be deployed to either the Repo or Share, and in fact large parts of the Alfresco application depend on repo-side java backed webscripts!

Comment: So tell me why I should use webscripts while I'm not even touching HTML...

Comment: Can you tell us at which location you have put `service-context.xml`?

Comment: service-context.xml is located at src/main/amp/config/alfresco/module/<name of project>/context

Comment: @Gagravarr Do you know how I could be able to reach my java code while it's in an AMP that's mapped onto the Alfresco.war?

Comment: Having a java-backed webscript in a repository AMP is perfectly normal and done by huge numbers of Alfresco installs. Just follow any tutorial!

Comment: I've done the [http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/ws-folderListing-Java-scripting.html tutorial] found on the official documentation website of Alfresco, but I don't see how I can alter that example to what I need. Could you link to a tutorial regarding this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! This is the solution for adding a file to the Repository:

CustomFileUpload.java:

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.Cache;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.Status;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException;
import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.repo.content.MimetypeMap;
import org.alfresco.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ContentWriter;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.StoreRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.ResultSet;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class CustomFileUpload extends DeclarativeWebScript {
    private final String UPLOAD_FILE_PATH = "{someRandomFile}";
    private final String UPLOAD_DESTINATION = "workspace://SpacesStore/{someRandomNodeRef}";
    protected ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public ServiceRegistry getServiceRegistry() {
        return serviceRegistry;
    }

    public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status, Cache cache) {
        File file = new File(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH);
//      NodeRef parent = getCompanyHome();
        NodeRef parent = new NodeRef(UPLOAD_DESTINATION);
        String name = "name of file in Repository " + System.currentTimeMillis();

        Map<QName, Serializable> props = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>(1);
        props.put(ContentModel.PROP_NAME, name);

        // use the node service to create a new node
        NodeRef node = serviceRegistry.getNodeService().createNode(
                        parent,
                        ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS,
                        QName.createQName(NamespaceService.CONTENT_MODEL_1_0_URI, name),
                        ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, props).getChildRef();

        // Use the content service to set the content onto the newly created
        // node
        ContentWriter writer = serviceRegistry.getContentService().getWriter(node, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT, true);
        writer.setMimetype(MimetypeMap.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);
        writer.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        String text = "";
        try {
            text = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.putContent(text);

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (status.getCode() == Status.STATUS_OK) {
            model.put("resultRepoWS", "File \"" + file.getName() + "\" uploaded successfully to the repository. Status: " + status.getCode());
            return model;
        } else {
            model.put("resultRepoWS", "There was an error while uploading document \"" + file.getName() + "\" - Status: " + status.getCode());
            return model;
        }
    }

    //If you want to test with CompanyHome first use this method instead of the NodeRef
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private NodeRef getCompanyHome() {
        StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore");
        serviceRegistry.getSearchService();
        ResultSet rs = serviceRegistry.getSearchService().query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_XPATH, "/app:company_home");
        NodeRef parent = null;
        try {
            if (rs.length() == 0) {
                throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("Didn't find Company Home");
            }
            parent = rs.getNodeRef(0);
        } finally {
            rs.close();
        }
        return parent;
    }
}
```

This java class is placed in the following folder:

> {tomcat}\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\org\example

Where org\example is the same as the package org.example. Now we have a class, now we need the configuration files as I call them:

> - customfileupload-context.xml

Which is located here

> - {tomcat}\shared\classes\alfresco\extension

You will also need these:

> - customfileupload.post.desc.xml
> - customfileupload.post.json.ftl

Which are located here

> - {tomcat}\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\webscripts\org\example

Noticed the folder? It's the same like the package mentioned earlier.

Contents of customfileupload-context.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN'
  'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd'>
<beans>
    <bean id="webscript.org.example.customfileupload.post" class="org.example.CustomFileUpload" parent="webscript">
        <property name="ServiceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Contents of customfileupload.post.desc.xml:

```
<webscript>
   <shortname>File Upload</shortname>
   <description>Upload files to user home</description>
   <url>/upload/fileupload.json</url>
   <format default="json"/>
   <authentication runas="admin">guest</authentication>
   <transaction>required</transaction>
</webscript>
```

Contents of customfileupload.post.json.ftl:

```
<#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)>  {  "resultRepoWS": "${resultRepoWS}"  }  </#escape>
```

This is it. With this you'll be able to upload a file to the Repository of Alfresco with Alfresco 5.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Autowired
NodeService nodeService
```

**Will not work in alfresco**

You need to inject it with proper setter method.
Your bean should be like below.

```
<bean id="somerandombeanname" class="management.FileManager" >
    <property name="moduleId" value="${project.artifactId}" />
    <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry" />
    <property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService" />
    <property name="transactionService" ref="TransactionService" />
    <property name="contentService" ref="ContentService" />
</bean>
```

Your java class should contain following for injecting nodeService.

```
private NodeService nodeService;

public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had at the time of asking the question. I shall include it explicitly in my question too because I did mention it. Anyways it still doesn't work.

Comment: are you using webscript ,policy or something else.can you please put your javacode as well?

Comment: The annotation was mentioned as way #1. The bean and setter are mentioned as way #2. The annotation was removed before I used the bean and setter way.

Comment: Nope, no webscript (this is repository, not share).

Comment: okay,your alfresco server is running and then you are executing code?

Comment: Yes, the Alfresco server is running and then I execute my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78154/discussion-between-krutik-jayswal-and-teysz).

Comment: Have you added setter for all other services which you are injecting? and you do not need to inject "serviceRegistry" if you are explicitly injecting required services.

Answer (score 3):

Luckily I have code for file upload thorugh JAVA backed webscript. Hope this help you too.To create java backed webscript see [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples)

Create one class named `CustomFileUpload.java` and put following content

```
package com.upload;

import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.Cache;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.Status;
import org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.MultipartRequestEntity;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.Part;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.StringPart;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CustomFileUpload extends DeclarativeWebScript {

    private final String UPLOAD_FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\Test\\Desktop\\test.txt";
    private int statusCode;

    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest arg0, Status status, Cache cache) {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            String URL = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/upload/fileupload?alf_ticket=" +getAlfticket();
            File file = new File(UPLOAD_FILE_PATH);
            String filetype = "text/plain";
            String filename = file.getName();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            PostMethod post = new PostMethod(URL);

            Part[] parts = {

                    new FilePart("filedata", filename, file, filetype, null),
                    new StringPart("filename", filename),
                    new StringPart("description", "This is test description"),
                    new StringPart("destination", "workspace://SpacesStore/bb424b1d-0418-4954-8591-b8c807264df0")
            };

            post.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, post.getParams()));
            statusCode = client.executeMethod(post);
            System.out.println(post.getResponseBodyAsString());
            post.releaseConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            model.put("result", "File uploaded successfully.");
            return model;
        } else {
            model.put("result", "There was an error while uploading document.");
            return model;
        }
    }

    private static String getAlfticket() throws IOException, JSONException {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin&format=json");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
        encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
        String json = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
        JSONObject getData = new JSONObject(json);

        return getData.getJSONObject("data").get("ticket").toString();
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** In destination you can put `nodeRef` of folder in which you want to upload.

Than create bean in context file name it whatever you want say `mycustom-context.xml` and put it in `ALFRESCO_HOME\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension` and content

```
<bean id="webscript.com.upload.customupload.post" class="com.upload.CustomFileUpload" parent="webscript">
</bean>
```

Finally register this web script in alfresco by creating `customupload.post.desc.xml`. and put

```
<webscript>
   <shortname>File Upload</shortname>
   <description>Upload files to user home</description>
   <url>/upload/fileupload?alf_ticket={ticket}</url>
   <format default="json"/>
   <authentication>user</authentication>
</webscript>
```

And last create view as we have declared JSON is default format so we need to create `customupload.post.json.ftl`

```
${result}
```

And put these both files in `ALFRESCO_HOME\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension\templates\webscripts\com\upload`

Now restart server and hit http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/upload/fileupload and you will see file uploaded in folder(Whatever you have given). For [Reference](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/uploading-files-using-restful-10182013-1327)

Comment: In ExecuteImpl you mention the URL is "/upload?alf_ticket=", but in the desc.xml you mention "/upload/fileupload?alf_ticket=". Shouldn't these be the same?

Comment: Ohh...sorry my mistake there should be `/upload/fileupload` in `executeImpl.java` :) I have modified code accordingly.

Comment: Is the bean id important? Or can I add anything I like to it? Or should it be something like `webscript.<package>.<class>.<HTTP method>`?

Comment: Yes it is important it must be like `webscript.<package>.<class>.<HTTP method>`. For simplicity `webscript.<package>.<filename of desc>.<HTTP method>`

Comment: Could you add a JSON example?

Comment: See the updated ans, change `CustomFileUpload.java` as well to get ouput in ftl.

Comment: I've added the files to the their destinations and tried to access that URL using PostMan so I can do the Post method. In PostMan it says it got a 200 statuscode, but the text returned in JSON shows that an error occured. So I tried to add the error to the `result` but it look likes it enters a infinit loop which renders the Repository inaccessible and I have to restart the server to fix the Repository. I've tried it over and over, the same thing keeps happening.

Comment: Can you show us how you passing error to result? Also show some tomcat logs as well.

Comment: This is the code: `string errormessage = ""; errormessage = e.getMessage(); model.put("result", "There was an error while uploading document - statuscode: " + statusCode + " - Error: " + errorMessage);` And this is the error: `ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-3] Tracking failed
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target...`

Comment: I am not sure but error looks like validation of certificate fails. I think something is wrong with your alfresco installation because code you have put doesn't lead webscript to infinite loop.

Comment: I've solved that error, but now no error is logged and it will not load in postman and cURL. I've checked all possible log files and it's not showing an error.

Comment: I've added a remote debugger to it and it looks like the debugger does the same as postman and will hang on the line: statusCode = client.executeMethod(post); Do you know why it would do that?

Comment: Try using `get method` instead of post once.