# Alfresco - How to create a Share web script that uses a Repository web script?

Tags: javascript, alfresco-webscripts

I'm trying to make a webscript on Alfresco Share (and potentially a dashlet) that uses/calls a webscript on the Repository tier. 
I know I need a description XML file, a javascript and a result page being HTML or JSON. My question is what should be in those files?

This what I have compiled from various sources in the interwebs ;)

Desc:

```
<webscript>
   <shortname>Some name</shortname>
   <description>Some description</description>
   <family>dashlet</family>
   <url>/components/dashlets/upload/fileupload</url>
</webscript>
```

Javascript:

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
var data = connector.get("/upload/fileupload");//URL of Repository webscript     

// create json object from data
var result = eval('(' + data + ')');//This will parse json data
model.resultaat = result["resultaat"];//For adding data to model.
```

HTML.ftl result:

```
<#if resultaat??>
    ${resultaat}
<#else>
    Oh no, the folder name is empty!
</#if>
```

What I'm actually trying to do is call a Repo webscript that generates and put a report in the Repository. This works (see [How to add a document to the Alfresco Repository with Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304918/how-to-add-a-document-to-the-alfresco-repository-with-java-code)), but I want to call this from Share. So any suggestions?

EDIT: Updated the files.

Comment: did you found answer this use full?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code which you need to put in Share JS controller(webscript.get.js) for connecting to Repository webscript.

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
var data = connector.get("/sample/docprop.json");//URL of Repository webscript     

// create json object from data
var result = eval('(' + data + ')');//This will parse json data
model.docprop = result["docprop"];//For adding data to model.
```

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot parse XML: Scanner State 24 not Recognized. It says it fails on line 5 of this example: customfileupload.get.js#5(eval)#1 Btw the data from my repo webscript is JSON, so I don't know why it's asking about XML.

Comment: If you see my comment , 3rd line is added for parsing json document and not xml.

Comment: It is JSON, I don't know why it says XML.

Comment: give me all files you can use pastebin

Comment: For the repo webscript files see the accepted answer of this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304918/how-to-add-a-document-to-the-alfresco-repository-with-java-code

Comment: Response of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304918/how-to-add-a-document-to-the-alfresco-repository-with-java-code webscript should be in proper json format.You can check json in jsonlint.com website.

Comment: jsonlint.com only says: Expecting '{', '[' on line 1 when I use the URL in it.

Comment: thats what , i was saying ,your json format is incorrect.Read more about what is json/

Comment: I added <#escape x as jsonUtils.encodeJSONString(x)> {  “resultaat”: "{$resultaat}"  }  </#escape> to my repo JSON.ftl and guess what it gives a JSON response, but your answer still doesn't work...

Comment: As i said ,read about json, ftl and webscript.You are not conceptually clear.

Comment: If only there was a site where I could ask questions... Oh wait. P.S. It IS a JSON response... What if the answer could be changed to XML instead? It seems it really wants XML.

Comment: did you get this line  var result = eval('(' + data + ')');//This will parse json data......Please dont responde if you are not getting

Comment: That is the line of doom where it all goes wrong. I am using that line, that IS the reason it is NOT working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82566/discussion-between-krutik-jayswal-and-teysz).

Comment: I've tried multiple times, changed files at both sides, and your answer still does not work. Could be because I'm trying to get a Repo web script that's  using the Post method with the connector.get of your answer?